# All Candidate keys are Superkeys whereas all Superkeys are not Candidate keys. Why?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the point of a candidate key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961455/whats-the-point-of-a-candidate-key)
>   [Superkey vs. Candidate key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087654/superkey-vs-candidate-key)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say the statement should be "... whereas not all Superkeys are Candidate keys". That's not the same, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of homework is that you do it yourself. Anyway, [Wikipedia supplies a clue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key)